How can I make this formula more dynamic by including another criteria (cell F11) in the query?
This formula currently queries data based on a criteria.
How can I include another criteria, which will result in a subset of the filtered by either both (C11 and F11) or one of them.
=if(C11<>"";
QUERY(Dados!A1:V;"select A, B, E, L, ' ', M, N, O, G, F, P, Q, R, T, I, J where H matches '"&C11&"'");
QUERY(Dados!A1:V;"select A, B, E, L, ' ', M, N, O, G, F, P, Q, R, T, I, J where A is not null label ' ' ' '"))

I guess it would be map based, but that is too new to me.
Here is the data and the expected result in the green background table:

...and here is the file, in case you feel like giving it a shot.

Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a minimal, reproducible example

Would you please include, along with the sample data, an example of the expected outcome(s).

Just did it, @Saddles. Thanks for your comment.

filtered by either both [Product] and [Company] or one of them. 1) Please update the formula in the question to match the layout in the image/data in the spreadsheet. 2) Please clarify: is the filter to be "Product" **and** "Company" OR "Product" **and/or** "Company". This formula will work for the former: =query({A4:E};"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null and Col1 = '"&H2&"' and Col2 = '"&J2&"'"); the later ("and/or") needs a different approach. 3) Please clarify if (and how) "Lote" is to be included in the query filter.

I guess I will do this cascaded query with multiple IFs , then. Thanks, @Tedinoz!

cascaded query with multiple IFs I'm not sure how that would be done. But, onit, please don't misunderstand me. I'm NOT trying to convince you that it is too hard or not worth doing. I'm simply asking you to clarify the question. Is it "Product" and "Company" OR "Product" and/or "Company", and what is the role of "Lote" in the query.

Related question: How to use query to filter data based on certain conditions in google sheet

You have sales data including "Product", "Company" and "Lota" (Load) and you want to query the data based on any combination of "Product" and/or "Company" and/or "Lote".
Consider this answer (applying an idea expressed by @MikeSteelson in How to use query to filter data based on certain conditions in google sheet).

Create two new sheets: "Search Results" and "Master List"

Create selection options by building Validation Rules on "Search Results"

In cells B2, B3 and B4 of "Search Results", create Validation Rules based on ranges in "Master List". Note that each rule includes an option = "Not filtered".
"Master List"

"Products:" Cell A2: =query({"Not filtered";'Página21'!A4:A13};"select *")
"Companies:" Cell C2=query({"Not filtered";'Página21'!B4:B13};"select *")
"Lote:" Cell E2 =query({"Not filtered";'Página21'!D4:D13};"select *")




Build IF statements on "Search Results"

Cell C2: =if(B2="Not filtered";;"Col1 matches '"&B2&"' ")
Cell C3: =if(B3="Not filtered";;"Col2 matches '"&B3&"'  ")
Cell C4: =if(B4="Not filtered";;"Col4 matches '"&B4&"'  ")
You can hide these formulas by setting the font colour to white.


Build the query formula on "Search Results"

In cell A6 =QUERY({'Cópia de Página21'!A3:E13};"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null and "&textjoin("and ";true;C2:C4)&" ";1)
select a "Product", "Company" or "Lote", or any combination;
where you don't want the "Product", Company" or "Lote" to be a criteria, select "Not filtered" for that option.




Search Results - one criteria


Search Results - two criteria


Master List - Validation Rules

